# Why is "Dynamic Links" created dynamically by android app not opening app directly?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

**Problem:**
Why is "Short dynamic links" created programatically wont open/launch the app directly?

> But link created at console, shows only one prompt to choose browser then app launches directly.

I want to launch app directly when user clicks the dynamic url created dynamically by android app.

When clicking dynamic short link created dynamically by android app the following things happen,

> 1.Option to open in browser shows
>
> 2.The browser opens,shows a loading dialog box
>
> 3.Again shows option to open in browser(this time app shows in the more options area)
>
> 4.Clicking browser opens website,clicking app lauches app but the deep link is lost.

Any Help would be great.

---

**Manifest.xml**

```
...
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data
      android:host="notifika.tupio.me"
       android:scheme="https" />
 </intent-filter>
...
```

**Link Generation**

```
  public void createDynamicLink(final Context context, final SingleNotification notification){
    final Uri[] mInvitationUrl = {null};
    String link = "https://notifika.tupio.me/?public=" + notification.getTag();
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse(link))
            .setDynamicLinkDomain("notifika.page.link")
            .setAndroidParameters(
                    new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("me.tupio.notifika")
                            .build())
            .setGoogleAnalyticsParameters(
                    new DynamicLink.GoogleAnalyticsParameters.Builder()
                            .setSource("In-App")
                            .setMedium("social")
                            .setCampaign("Word-Word")
                            .build())
            .setSocialMetaTagParameters(
                    new DynamicLink.SocialMetaTagParameters.Builder()
                            .setTitle("Notifika")
                            .setDescription("Sent and Receive Notification like this.Download the app now")
                            .build())

            .buildShortDynamicLink()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(ShortDynamicLink shortDynamicLink) {
                    mInvitationUrl[0] = shortDynamicLink.getShortLink();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, notification.getTitle()+"\n"+notification.getMessage().substring(0, Math.min(notification.getMessage().length(), 100)) + "..." +context.getResources().getString(R.string.share_link_desc)+"\n"+mInvitationUrl[0]);
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
                }
            });

}
```

MainActivity.class

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                    Uri deepLink = null;
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                        deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                        Log.v("Deeplink",deepLink.toString());
                    }
                    //
                    // If the user isn't signed in and the pending Dynamic Link is
                    // an invitation, sign in the user anonymously, and record the
                    // referrer's UID.
                    //
                    if (deepLink != null
                            && deepLink.getBooleanQueryParameter("public",false)) {
                        String referrerUid = deepLink.getQueryParameter("public");
                        Log.v("Deeplink", referrerUid);
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),referrerUid,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Followed [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/rewarded-referral) guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to add an intent filter for your page.link/app.goo.gl domain as well, so the deep link goes straight to your app. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive#app_links

Comment: A complete solution can be found here- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55644902/7944002